# Is there a customizable form in drupal similar to the contact form?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-contact-form, drupal-modules

I need a form to enable user to enter event info in three fields (what, where, and when). Then I would like to be able to present the events in tabular form. I don't know PHP. Does drupal have a module for this purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [content construction kit (CCK)](http://drupal.org/project/cck) allows you to create content types with custom fields, and automatically produces the forms for those content types. You'll probably also want the [date field](http://drupal.org/project/date) for the when.

Answer (score 1):

You would use Views to display data as a table.

http://www.drupal.org/project/views

Answer (score 0):

- [**Drupal Form Builder**](http://drupal.org/project/form_builder)

Will create quick forms for you on the go.

- [**Drupal CCK**](http://drupal.org/project/cck)

This one is a little bit more envolved, but more definitive, common place, and HIGHLY extensible. Here's a [nice little tutorial](http://heim.ifi.uio.no/inf5270/tutorials/cck.html) as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the results (events) to turn into nodes when the user enters the data and submit the form, then you should look into the webform module.

A while back I "demoed" this to my peers by building a "mcdonald's monopoly" tracker that anyone could use to input their pieces and then I setup a view as a block to display the aggregate result for everyone's pieces.

We didn't win anything, but this may be what you are looking for.